# Oracle SQL query to pull data and add new created date column

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I'm quite new to Oracle SQL so please excuse me if my question actually has a relatively schoolboy answer.

So I have 2 tables, Apps and Apps_history with the definitions below.

```
     Apps                Apps_history
     ID                  ID
     Other               APP_ID
     DATE_MODIFIED       STATUS
                         DATE_MODIFIED
```

Apps_history has app_id which is a foreign key of the primary key ID in Apps, records in Apps are frequently updated and Apps_history keeps track of this. I want a new column to show when an ID in apps was created, this can be derived from the column date_modified in Apps_History when state is equal to 'initialized'.

Currently this is what I have

```
    select *, t.date_modified as create_date
    (select app_history.date_modified 
    from apps  
    inner join app_history on 
    apps.id=app_history.app_id where 
    status='initialized') T 
    from apps;
```

But I'm getting some errors, any help to nudge me in the right direction is much appreciated,

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to accomplish this.  You seem to have started down the road of a correlated subquery, so to continue with that:

```
select a.*,
       (select ah.date_modified 
        from app_history ah 
        where a.id = ah.app_id and ah.status = 'initialized')
       ) as created_date 
from apps a;
```

For performance, I would recommend an index on `app_history(app_id, status, date_modified)`.

Answer (score 0):

Your subquery is not correlated. You could solve this using a correlated query as suggested by @Gordon. Also, it would throw error if you are getting multiple rows from the correlated subquery but that's fixable.

I'd use left self join for this.

```
select a.*,
    t.date_modified as create_date
from apps a
left join apps t on a.id = t.app_id
    and t.status = 'initialized';
```